# how much load can a cloudfront hosted site handle?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I am new to AWS cloudFront. We have our static assets (css, js, images) hosted in a S3 bucket and serving them from CloudFront. Our front-end (ReactJS) is served from a load balancer with a few EC2 instances which send the `index.html` file that fetches the chunks (build files css, js) from cloudfront. Previously we had to do a template rendering on the `index.html` on every client request.

We have decided to remove the template rendering part and serve the front-end directly from cloudFront. Is it a good idea have the front-end be directly served cloudFront? and can cloudFront handle the load? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default limits can be seen here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html

> Requests per second per distribution - 250,000

> Data transfer rate per distribution - 150 Gbps

You mentioned you have some assets served by ec2 instances, you may want to monitor the metrics when taking on load, see how its faring.

But if you are just serving html files, I think it should be ok.